# Javascript memory leaks when object property references the object itself (self reference)

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's say I have a code like this

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = obj;
```

I know that modern browsers implement Mark-and-sweep algorithm which should not have memory leaks in this case. But I'm not sure whether old browsers that implement reference-counting consider this as a circular reference.

In my opinion, there should be a memory leak because the reference count is 1 (referenced by the "a" property of the same object). Am I correct that the reference count is 1 or the browser does not increase the reference count if the object is referenced by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older browsers (I'm assuming you're talking about things like IE6) don't have a problem with the reference you list as it's entirely contained within javascript and they handle it fine.

Where older browsers have circular reference problems is when you have circular references between javascript objects and DOM objects.  If you don't store DOM objects in persistent javascript variables or you don't store references to javascript objects in DOM properties, then you won't run into this issue.  It is no longer an issue in modern browsers either.

Comment: you mean it will leak if i update the first line to var obj=document.getElementById()

Comment: @KhanhTo - no.  You have to have a DOM object property that points to javascript object and the same javascript object that has a property that points to that DOM object.  Circular reference between DOM and javascript.

Comment: Why is there a difference between DOM objects and javascript objects? Why does the algorithm care about whether it's a javascript object or DOM object?

Comment: @KhanhTo - Because javascript and the DOM each have or had separate garbage collectors as they are separate systems and that's what led to the problem.

Comment: it's good to know that. Do you have any links to any official documents so I can read more about the separate garbage collector. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KhanhTo - no I don't have any links.  This is just knowledge gained over years and years of reading and working with this stuff.  I don't know where the original sources of info are.  Just remember that javascript is, for the most part, it's own standalone system that interfaces into a browser.  The javascript engine can be used outside of a browser and a browser can be used with javascript disabled.  If you Google "browser memory leaks", you can probably find articles written about it.  As far as I know, all systemic leak issues like this are no longer a problem.

Comment: From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index3.shtml, I found out that when we have circular references between javascript object and DOM objects, even mark-and-sweep still has memory leaks: 

"Since the JScript garbage collector is a mark and sweep GC, you may think that it would handle circular references. And in fact it does. However this circular reference is between the DOM and JS worlds. DOM and JS have separate garbage collectors.Therefore they cannot clean up memory in situations like the above."

Comment: Therefore, I think my doubt is still valid. What you said is another case, not the case in my question.

Comment: @KhanhTo - if you want to know if your specific case causes a leak in a particular browser, then it would be best to just write a test case and run the test.